# mysqli_real_escape_string AND prepared statements?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

Should be a simple enough question:

If I am using mysqli prepared statements, do I still need to use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` as well?

Is this necessary, or a good idea?

Thanks, Nico

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No.  If you use prepared statements, escaping is done for you.