# MySQLi Injection prevention with prepared statements

Tags: php, mysqli

I know this type of  question has already been asked many time .

My question is

> Are the prepared statements intelligent enough to prevent injection or
>   do we need  to use , these with prepared statements.

```
mysqli_real_escape_string ()
htmlentities()
```

etc

My Prepared MySQLi statement.

```
$username = $user['user_name']; // current user session
$user_to  = 'admin';     // always admin
$date     = date('Y-m-d');
$title    = $_POST['title'] ;    //user input
$message  = $_POST['message'];    // user input
$read     = "yes";  //user_from read value
$read1    =  "no";   //user_to read value

//send message now 
$query = "INSERT INTO TABLENAME (user_from, user_to, title, message, date, user_from_read, user_to_read) 
VALUES(?, ?, ?,?,?,?,?)";
$statement = $MySQLi_CON->prepare($query);
$statement->bind_param('sssssss', $username, $user_to, $title ,$message,$date,$read,$read1);
if($statement->execute()) 
    { 
    //echo success 
    }
    else
    {
    //echo failure
    }
```

2: how do I check whether user is not trying to attack the site via title and message inputs. and warn him incase he is attempting to do so .

Comment: You're doing it right! This prevents SQL Injection. But not XSS attacks!

Comment: @AlexisPeters , so how to prevent from XSS and other attacks , Which approach shall I using ???

Comment: htmlspecialchars does the XSS - prevent job. If you want to prohibit the user to use html-tags or PHP - tags at all, sanitize you inputs with strip_tags.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mysqli\_real\_escape\_string AND prepared statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162540/mysqli-real-escape-string-and-prepared-statements)